# subsetting a data frame according factor date

Tags: r

I have a data frame(df) where one of its column is a date column. However that column's type is factor:

```
> head(df$date)
[1] 2011-01-01 2011-01-01 2011-01-01 2011-01-01 2011-01-01 2011-01-01
1519 Levels: 2010-11-27 2010-11-28 2010-11-29 2010-11-30 2010-12-01 2010-12-02 2010-12-03 2010-12-04 ... 2015-02-07
```

I want to subset this data frame according to date. For example I want to create a second data frame(df2) where it is a subset of df where dates are smaller than 2014-03-30.

How can I do that using R? I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @oercim You can convert to `date` class by `as.Date` i.e. `as.Date(factor(c('2011-01-01', '2011-01-02', '2011-01-03', '2014-04-25'))) < as.Date('2014-03-30')` .  For your dataset `df[as.Date(df$date)< as.Date('2014-03-30'),]`

Comment: @akrun, thanks a lot. That worked very well as all of your answers.

Answer (score 3):

You could begin exploring the `lubridate` library.  It makes working with dates very simple.

```
df <- data.frame(date = c("2013-01-01", "2014-04-01", "2014-01-01",
                          "2011-06-01", "2012-03-01", "2014-08-01"))
df
        date
1 2013-01-01
2 2014-04-01
3 2014-01-01
4 2011-06-01
5 2012-03-01
6 2014-08-01

library(lubridate)
# ymd - year-month-day
df$date <- ymd(df$date)
with(df, df[date < ymd("2014-03-30"),])
[1] "2013-01-01 UTC" "2014-01-01 UTC" "2011-06-01 UTC" "2012-03-01 UTC"
```